# Array of objects created in if statement (scope issue)

Tags: java, arrays, scope

The program begins with a prompt to:

1. create a new list of students
2. search for a student.

**Problem:** I create an object array and populate it in the first if statement then try to access it in the second if statement, which I know I can't do.  So how can I create and populate the array of objects and access it later?  Any ideas?

```
if(iUserSelection == 1) {

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("How many students?");
    x = oScan.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    // flush the buffer
    oScan.nextLine();

    Student[] oClassList = new Student[x];
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        System.out.println("*********************");
        System.out.println("Student " + (i + 1) + " of " + x);
        System.out.println("*********************");

        oClassList[i] = new Student("","",0,0,0,0);

        System.out.print("First Name: ");
        oClassList[i].setFirstName(oScan.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Last Name: ");
        oClassList[i].setLastName(oScan.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Homework average: ");
        oClassList[i].setHWAve(oScan.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Quiz average: ");
        oClassList[i].setQuizAve(oScan.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Project average: ");
        oClassList[i].setProjectAve(oScan.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Test average: ");
        oClassList[i].setTestAve(oScan.nextInt());

        // flush the buffer
        oScan.nextLine();

        System.out.println();
        oClassList[i].printStudent();
    }
}

if(iUserSelection == 2) {
    // flush the buffer
    oScan.nextLine();

    if(oClassList[0] != null) { 
        System.out.println("Student search");

        System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
        sSearchLastName = oScan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
        sSearchFirstName = oScan.nextLine();
    }

    for(int y = 0; y >= oClassList.length; y++) {
        if(sSearchLastName == oClassList[y].lastName) {
            System.out.println("found elements");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Error - Student not found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep the array from being deleted when the if-statement exits, declare it outside of the if-statement, giving it a wider scope. The array can then be populated inside of the if-statement without going outside of scope when the if statement exits. For example,

```
int[] arr;
if (true) {
    arr = new int[1];
    arr[0] = 5;
}
System.out.println(arr[0]);
```

Output:

```
5
```

arr will maintain its value when the exiting the if-statement because it was declared outside of the if-statement and then instantiated inside.

Your corrected code would be:

```
Student[] oClassList;                //Declared outside of both if-statements

if(iUserSelection == 1) {

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("How many students?");
    x = oScan.nextInt();

    System.out.println();


    // flush the buffer
    oScan.nextLine();

    oClassList = new Student[x];

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        System.out.println("*********************");
        System.out.println("Student " + (i + 1) + " of " + x);
        System.out.println("*********************");


        oClassList[i] = new Student("","",0,0,0,0);


        System.out.print("First Name: ");
        oClassList[i].setFirstName(oScan.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Last Name: ");
        oClassList[i].setLastName(oScan.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Homework average: ");
        oClassList[i].setHWAve(oScan.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Quiz average: ");
        oClassList[i].setQuizAve(oScan.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Project average: ");
        oClassList[i].setProjectAve(oScan.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Test average: ");
        oClassList[i].setTestAve(oScan.nextInt());



        // flush the buffer
        oScan.nextLine();

        System.out.println();



        oClassList[i].printStudent();
    }
}

if(iUserSelection == 2) {
    // flush the buffer
    oScan.nextLine();

    if(oClassList[0] != null) { 
        System.out.println("Student search");

        System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
        sSearchLastName = oScan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
        sSearchFirstName = oScan.nextLine();
    }


    for(int y = 0; y >= oClassList.length; y++) {
        if(sSearchLastName == oClassList[y].lastName) {
            System.out.println("found elements");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Error - Student not found");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already know your answer. It is a scope issue, so the solution is define your array in a "wider" scope, that your second if also sees. So, basically define it before if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Scope is defined by blocks, a block is delimited by brackets `{}`. If you create the array inside the `if` block, you won't be able to access to it in the other `if` block.

**How to solve this?** You can declare the array in an outer block, so you can access to it in all that block.

```
Student[] oClassList = null;

if (iUserSelection == 1) {
    // ...
    oClassList = new Student[x];
    // ...
}

if (iUserSelection == 2) {
    if(oClassList != null)
        // ...
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Great.  I can do that but x is defined in the first if statement.

Comment: @SkilletSpecial Edited to fit your requirements. You can declare the array first, and then when you have `x` you can *initialize* it. Note that if you do this, you can get `null` if you enter the second `if`and the array was not initalized yet. To check this you can use `if (oClassList != null)`

Comment: Ok I declared the array first.  The only remaining issue is in the second if statement.  The 'local variable oClassList may not have been initialized.'  But if I initialize Student[] oClassList = null; then I get a NullPointerException.

Comment: Yes, that's why you have to check `if (oClassList != null) { // do some operations with oClassList}`.